# Getting index position of string in List C#

Tags: c#, loops, position, startswith

Trying to get the index position of a string in a List but it keeps returning zero(0) as the index integer variable.

Any ideas what is wrong? I have tried changing to public int and so on.

```
        public int GetLangPos(string cultureCode)
    {


        CsvRead csvRead = new CsvRead();


        int index = 0;
        foreach (string line in csvRead.headerNames)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith(cultureCode)) { return index; }
            index++;
        }
        return index;
    }
```

CsvRead class:

```
class CsvRead
{

    public List<CsvLine> _csvLines = new List<CsvLine>(); //stores the csv lines
    public List<string> headerNames = new List<string>(); //stores the headers of the csv file

    public void GetValue()
    {

        /*
        Key|Name|es-ES|fr-FR|ru-RU
        web_key_001|Message|Mensaje|Message|Сообщение //row0
        web_key_002|Close|Cerca|Fermer|Закрыть //row1
        web_key_003|Administration|Administración|Administration|Aдминистрация //row2
        web_key_004|Confirm|Confirmar|Confirmer|подтвердить //row3
        web_key_005|Success|Éxito|Succès|Yспех //row4
        */

        FileStream f = new FileStream(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TranslationsCsv"], FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(f);
        CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration();
        config.Delimiter = "|";
        CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, config);


        using (csvReader)
        {
            while (csvReader.Read())
            {
                headerNames = csvReader.FieldHeaders.ToList<string>();



                CsvLine csvLine = new CsvLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < headerNames.Count(); i++)
                {
                    csvLine.fieldValues.Add(csvReader.GetField<string>(headerNames.ElementAt(i)));
                }

                _csvLines.Add(csvLine);


            }


            //test section start



            //test section end

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: csvRead has any headerNames in it? It looks like you aren't reading anything there.

Comment: please add simple data better understanding

Comment: headerNames just contains 5 elements. And the cultureCode variable is always present somewhere in the list of headerNames.

Comment: Your code looks good, index is 0 either there are no headerNames in cvsRead or the first line starts with cultureCode

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Without anything concrete, this is just a guessing game.

Comment: There is definitely headerNames inside csvRead and elements inside the list too. Just test printed the elements at a good point in the program with a breakpoint and it's full of cultureCodes. :(

Comment: Added the CsvRead class :)

Comment: Are they in the same case? the cultureinfo and the headers?

Comment: different classes. :)

Comment: It looks an awful lot like you're just creating a new `CsvRead` instance and never calling `GetValue`, so I'd expect `headerNames` to be empty.  You need to step through this with a debugger.

Comment: I did not mean classes. Are they in upper case or lower case? You are not using string.startswith with ignorecase set to true.

Comment: They are a mix of upper and lower case in the cultureCode.

Comment: GetValue is called before that method is called in the main :)

Comment: and the header is also in the same mixed case? just trying to rule out a simple case mismatch.

Comment: @TingAli you create a new instance, you then read the `headerNames`.  You aren't calling `GetValue` between them, so `headerNames` will be empty.  The fact you might have another instance you call `GetValue` on isn't relevant, *this* instance won't have *that* instance's state.  Stick a break point before your loop and look at it.

Comment: @CharlesMager You're a genius! Thank you!! I didn't realise that I had to call the GetValue again due to the new instance! Post a answer with that comment and I'll give you the answer thing on here! Cheers mate! :)

Comment: Don't ask people to find error of your application. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815788

Comment: @TingAli ideally, you shouldn't do this.  You've already read the file once, you should be using the same instance of `CsvRead` to find this column rather than reading it a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be a misunderstanding in how object instances work.

When you create an instance of a class using the `new` operator, you create a new instance of that object.  The values of that object's instance fields (those without the `static` modifier) will belong to *that instance only*.

If you've called `GetValue` on some instance in `Main`, as you suggest, then the 'new' instance you create at `GetLangPos` will not share any of the state of this other instance.

As you've already read the file, you should probably re-use the results of that by re-using that instance rather than creating a new one in `GetLangPos` and reading the file again.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 possible reasons:

1. you are not filling headerNames
2. you are not creating or initializing the headerNames list

Please post all the code to check the CsvRead internals

---- Edit ----

you have to take the line:

```
headerNames = csvReader.FieldHeaders.ToList<string>();
```

out of the while loop, that is reading the headers in all iterations and the line at the end of file is empty.

```
csvReader.Read(); // read the headers
headerNames = csvReader.FieldHeaders.ToList<string>();
while (csvReader.Read())
{
...
}
```

Comment: Posted it just now :)

Comment: Where do i put that line after? :)